# Making a Form globally accessible through the application

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

In my VS-2008 Windows application, I want to show a popup form with progress bar on it. A class running in the background should directly send progress bar values to it. I want this Form to be accessible directly by typing its name and not by creating instances.

If I set it's Accessible Role property to Dialog, it will come on top and will interfere with user's work. I want this Form to run in some corner of the screen and should appear as a child of the MDI form but should be accessible directly.

Comment: Winforms or WPF?  What have you tried?

Comment: @Kyle The use of the word "Form" seems to indicate WinForms.

Comment: You should search for progressbar tutorial on Google. You'll have many complete solutions. You can't show a form without instanciating it. It's against OOP logic (if I understood well your question)

Comment: It is a WinForms application as I have also written use of MDI Form. I guess WPF does not have MDI directly.

Comment: @Mathieu: I know how a progress bar works, but I want to control this Form when user is working on another Form.

Comment: @Mathieu I thought you can .Show() a static form class. I'm pretty sure you can.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

The simplest way is to make your whole class static, and change all instance variables and methods to static. Then you can call the methods by class name, like `MyFormClass.UpdateProgress(2);`

Doing it this way is ugly to some people (including me) who would prefer you to store a single non-static instance of your class somewhere and control access to it through a control object/method. I'm not sure how much of that opinion is legitimate in the C# world of implementation-worries-free programming.

Also if you're planning on updating the progress bar from a background thread keep in mind that winforms are not threadsafe.